# Kivmob not showing ad banner for android kivy application

Tags: python, android, kivy, admob, buildozer

I am trying to get an ad banner on my Kivy android app. Below is the test app that was referenced from [this website](http://kivmob.com/tutorials.html).

```
from kivmob import KivMob, TestIds

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label

class BannerTest(App):
    """ Displays a banner ad at top of the screen.
    """

    def build(self):
        self.ads = KivMob(TestIds.APP)
        self.ads.new_banner(TestIds.BANNER, top_pos=True)
        self.ads.request_banner()
        self.ads.show_banner()
        return Label(text='Banner Ad Demo')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    BannerTest().run()
```

I have also setup my bulldozer.spec file to look like this:

```
requirements = kivy, android, jnius, kivmob
...
android.permissions = INTERNET, ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE
android.api = 27
android.minapi = 21
android.sdk = 24
android.ndk = 19b
android.gradle_dependencies = 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:10.2.0'
p4a.branch = master
# For test ads, use application ID ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713
android.meta_data = com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID=ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713
```

I can successfully deploy it to my android but when I do I just get a "Banner Ad Demo" text in the middle of the screen and no actual banner ad popping up. What am I missing?

Comment: I tried yesterday with the same result (my own keys and all). Seems like the support has been dropped with the android api 27. Have you had a look at kivmob27 ? The python-for-android27 is outdated (not the master branch) so I can't build. There is a way to modify p4a-master (search for a blogpost) but it hasn't worked for me either.

Answer (score 0):

Please add python3 in requirements buildizer.spec file
Also make android api to 28

Answer (score 0):

Use this Enum of test ad ids provided by AdMob. This allows developers to test displaying ad without setting up an AdMob account.

http://kivmob.com/kivmob.html

You can replace TestIds.App with 'ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713'
That is self.ads = KivMob('ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713')

And also
self.ads.new_banner('ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111', top_pos=True)